# Cookie is set in firefox, but not in chrome

Tags: asp.net, cookies

Iframe is used to load second web page (with different domain) in the first one. Cookie is set for second page, but it seems that in Firefox it is set, but in chrome not. It was working months ago.

Cookie is created with this code in asp.net:

```
  cookie = new HttpCookie("name", "value")
            {
                Domain = 'domain of second page',
                Secure = true,
                SameSite = SameSiteMode.None
            };
```

What can be solution for this issue?

Comment: It probably won't be long before Firefox stops working too. You should really ask yourself if the iframe is needed. My guess you could do without if you own both sites.

Comment: I do not own both sites, so I am looking for the solution

Comment: Why would you set a cookie for a site you do not own? I'm glad Chrome blocks this kind of stuff and Firefox should fix this asap.

Comment: I set cookie for second page (which I own) and it's not set if samesite!=none

Comment: I found out that it's fixed with windows update